# Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'M' in D:\SERVIDOR\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4952

Tags: php, wordpress

Yesterday it was well, today i couldn't see the headers (WordPress) and it said:

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'M' in D:\SERVIDOR\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4952

I went to that localitation:

```html
function wp_is_stream( $path ) {
 $wrappers = stream_get_wrappers();
 $wrappers_re = '(' . join('|', $wrappers) . ')';

 return preg_match( "!^$wrappers_re://!", $path ) === 1;
}
```

Comment: Probe what `$wrappers_re` contains then.

Comment: That variable must have a `!` in it. You'll need to change the delimiter or escape all the `!`s.